# create a box in RML report

Tags: report, odoo, rml

I like to display the text message within the box like structure.

```
<para fontSize="8.0">All goods supplied are subject to our standard terms and condition, a copy on which available upon request.</para>
<para fontSize="8.0">All shortages, discrepancies or damages must be reported to order@xxxxx.co.uk within 48 hours of delivery.</para>
```

So the above para content should be placed within the box like structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then add a table and specify border

Answer (score 0):

```
<blockTableStyle id="Table_4">
  <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
  <blockValign value="TOP"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEBEFORE" colorName="#000000" start="0,0" stop="0,-1"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEABOVE" colorName="#000000" start="0,0" stop="0,0"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="0,-1" stop="0,-1"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEBEFORE" colorName="#000000" start="1,0" stop="1,-1"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEABOVE" colorName="#000000" start="1,0" stop="1,0"/>
  <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="1,-1" stop="1,-1"/>
</blockTableStyle>

<blockTable repeatRows="1" style="Table_4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre4">All goods supplied are subject to our standard terms and condition, a copy on which available upon request.</para>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre4">All shortages, discrepancies or damages must be reported to yyyyyy@xxxxxx.co.uk within 48 hours of delivery.</para>
    </td>
  </tr>
</blockTable>
```